# Interpreter representation of a tuple to allow for efficient unpacking

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, tuples, interpreter

## My Implementation Attempt

I'm attempting to implement tuple unpacking in my interpreter. To represent a tuple, I'm using a class `Tuple` with a vector `members` that can store any value `Value` in the language:

```
typedef std::variant<int, float, std::string, Tuple> Value; //Note - ignore the "Tuple" circular dependency - this code is just for illustration purposes

class Tuple {
public:
      const std::vector<Value> members;
      Tuple(std::vector<Type> _members) : members(_members) {}
};
```

The unpacking of a tuple is python-like in syntax with a variable list on the LHS and the tuple on the right.

```
(a, (b, c), d) = (1, (2, 3), 4)
```

The RHS of the above code is represented by the tuple class above as `Tuple example({1, Tuple({2, 3}), 4});`

For some background, in my interpreter I'm using a AST with the visitor pattern to construct `Value` objects and assign them to variables when a assign statement is visited. The above RHS tuple object `example` is generated when a `TupleNode` representing the expression (`(1, (2, 3), 4)`) is visited. The entire statement (`(a, (b, c), d) = (1, (2, 3), 4)`) is represented by a `UnpackNode` with left side pointing to a vector of identifiers (`(a, (b, c), d)`) and right side pointing to the `TupleNode` previously discussed.

When a `UnpackNode` is visited, it first works out what the Tuple Object (`example`) and then iterates over every identifier on the LHS of the statement, assigning it to a `members` value of the Tuple object at the same index of the identifier on the LHS.

## Concerns

Using the approach described above has caused significant performance hits when using tuples. The two code snippets below yields the same results but using the tuples and unpacking is approx ~20x slower.

```
(a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3) //approx 20x slower then equivalent code below
_______
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

Is representing the contents of a Tuple with a vector of vectors a good idea (performance wise) considering that it will be iterated over quite frequently? Would it instead be a better idea to flatten the vector and use some other system to work out how to index the tuple (for situations where there is tuples of tuples)? What would be an efficient way to iterate over a tuple in order to extract certain values?

If anyone has any general advice or tips on tuple implementations of resources they could link that would very much be appreciated. Or if anyone has any criticisms with my approach or can suggest a better way of doing so please feel free to let me know. There's not a lot of material on tuple unpacking in relation to compiler/interpreter design so I would be very appreciative of any information that could be provided in the context of their implementation.

Comment: _"...vector of vectors..."_ has terrible locality.

Comment: @RichardCritten Very true. Struggling to think of alternative solutions.

Comment: Python itself seems to handle that particular case by not building the tuple in the first place. You should be able to statically compile any destructuring left-hand side into the series of assignments it represents. (Unless your language has real reference values, I guess.)

Comment: @rici In terms of AST, are you suggesting that instead of a single unpack node - there should be multiple assignment nodes instead?

Comment: @tom: i guess that depends on your design. If you have an unpack node, you probably have a pack node as well, which presumably is a child of the unpack node. Eliminating both is a possible optimisation, but you need to be able to put the computed values somewhere; otherwise `a, b = b, a` won't work as expected. Python (and other languages) use the interpreter stack for this purpose, but you might not have one.